# Access-Control-Allow-Origin possible threats on static JS file

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript, ajax

As I am working on a research, I need allow users to read my JavaScript file using Ajax. However, I want to make sure about consequences of adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for just this file.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I know about the goal of origin control and all examples about accessing behalf of user. However, **enabling this feature for just one static JS file can cause any security problem?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can really cause any harm on a Javascript file. The problem starts when this is possible on a web page.